# Loading texture ? - SFML 2.1 - VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sfml

after a couple of years of inactivity, I am trying to learn how to use SFML.net with vs2013.
(as XNA is discontinued, I had to learn something new).

I am struggling to do a very simple texture loading. Here is what I did :

- Created a new windows console solution.
- loaded SFML (via Nugget PM)
- Created a resources folder (Project settings)
- loaded a basic texture in this resource folder

The program loads the texture, creates a sprite with this texture, positions it and draws it. Should be a gentle start right ? Except that it gives me an error saying that the texture cannot be loaded.

(PS : SFML seems to be a very good library in C++ but the documentation is very poor in other languages to my point of view)

Here is the (very simple) code :

```
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;
using SFML.Audio;
using System;

namespace SFMLApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static readonly Color CornflowerBlue = new Color(100, 149, 237);
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML Window");
            window.Closed += (sender, eventArgs) => window.Close();

            while (window.IsOpen())
            {
                window.DispatchEvents();
                // TODO: Insert Update Code Here
                Texture playertxr = new Texture("sonic.png");
                Sprite playerspr = new Sprite(playertxr);
                playerspr.Position = new Vector2f(200, 400);
                window.Clear(CornflowerBlue);
                // TODO: Insert Draw Code Here
                window.Draw(playerspr);
                window.Display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to include the stack trace & message for any exceptions you're getting.

Comment: Error says :
An unhandled exception of type 'SFML.LoadingFailedException' occurred in sfmlnet-graphics-2.dll
Additional information: Failed to load texture from file sonic.png

Comment: Found the solution (after trying many many things) :
`Texture playertxr = new Texture(@"resources\sonic.png");`